# How to specify a particular instant or moment with a noun?

Tags: word-request

With *only* a noun, I wish to refer to the M minute S second of something, such as a video.
For example, [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/22473/8572), I used 'mark' but question its correctness. What are apter noun(al) synonyms? Is 'juncture' ?
I ask only for the noun, NOT for a rewrite without the noun.

Comment: Yes, *mark* is perfectly idiomatic; *juncture* is a little purple.  commonly we simply use the preposition *at*, as in "*at 2:32 in this video*...", or *starting at* to emphasize the continuing nature of the content (as opposed to simply the single instant 2:32).

Answer (score 2):

@Dan Bron is right.

> Stop the video at the 4 minute 30 second mark.

Or:

> Stop the video at 4 minutes 30 seconds.

Both of those work and sound natural.

Don't use *juncture*, *juncture* is more for expressing something like where two roads or pipes connect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had intended to ask a different question. What nouns are (better) synonyms than **mark** ? I ask only for the noun, rather than a rewrite without the noun. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit If that is your question, please edit your OP to ask *that*, rather than allow more people to answer the question as it is *currently* asked.

Comment: You could also use the word "point."  It's not better, but equivalent.  "Spot" could also work.

Comment: @ultrasawblade Thank you for your comments. Again, I do apologise for any confusion; I simply hadn't realised that my OP failed to be precise enough. Better now? Please do feel free to edit your own answer to include further suggestions.